# Bulkify trigger and error handler

Tags: trigger

I need to bulkify the trigger and error handler.Can someone point me if my trigger is bukified  or not and handled error ?

```
 trigger KeyGenerator on Account (before insert,before update) {

    for(Account UpdatedAcc:Trigger.new)
    {
       if(UpdatedAcc.Key__c == null)
          {  

            String KeyStartWith = UpdatedAcc.Name.replace(' ','');
            KeyStartWith = KeyStartWith.toLowerCase();
            //Get the first 5 letter of Account Name
            if(KeyStartWith.length()<=5)
            {
             KeyStartWith=KeyStartWith.substring(0,KeyStartWith.length());
            }else
            {
                KeyStartWith=KeyStartWith.substring(0,5);
            }
            //Get the number generated randomly
            Double randomDouble=Math.random();
            //Crop the last five digits of this generated number
            String KeyEndWith=String.valueOf(randomDouble);
            KeyEndWith=KeyEndWith.substring(KeyEndWith.length()-5,KeyEndWith.length());

          try{
            UpdatedAcc.Key__c=KeyStartWith+KeyEndWith;
            }
           catch(Exception e){
            UpdatedAcc.addError('Failed to update Key');
           } 
          }  
     }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [General trigger bulkification - best practices](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your trigger is bulkified in the sense that it handles SOQL queries and DML statements in a bulkified way (you don't have DML or SOQL). If the assignment of Key__c failed you will have working error handling - however If your other code fails you are not handling exceptions well.

What if Name is null for example - not sure it can happen - but if it can you would end up with an unhandled exception due to a null-pointer-exception on the replace call.

Comment: Name is standard field for all kind of objects and it is always required, but it can happend that it  is an auto-number.
From my point I can't see here any issue, try{} catch(){} block is most useful for DML operations, but in before triggers as this I don't see a point of using it.